# Obtain Location Query before Querying the Parse Table

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, location

I was having issues with obtaining the location of the user and then running a `PFQuery` for the class. The issue I am having is when I launch the app the tableview loads an empty data set. I know the query is working fine because when I refresh the tableview with the pull down method it loads the right data set with the right location.

So I suspect when I first launch the application the query runs before obtaining the location, but then after I manually refresh the tableview the location has been obtained from the location manager and the right data set is loaded.

I referenced these two posts...

[Location Query in Parse TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21445979/location-query-in-parse-tableview)

[Locations around the users with parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923761/locations-around-the-users-with-parse)

But, was having a lot of trouble when placing the `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` in the `viewDidLoad` with the query inside of it or placing it in a separate function with the query inside of it (I have a separate function called `queryForData` which allows the pull to refresh to work, but I remove that function when adding the `PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground`)...

Whichever I do, the Query does not work successfully as the all the rows in the class are loaded instead of just the data rows that apply to the user's current location.

```
  override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    if let userLocation = currLocation {
        query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: PFGeoPoint(latitude: userLocation.latitude, longitude: userLocation.longitude), withinKilometers: 5)
        query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    } else {

    }
    return query
}
```

And then I was using this code from that other stackoverflow question I posted...

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
(point:PFGeoPoint!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
if error == nil {
    //Point contains the user's current point

    //Get a max of 100 of the restaurants that are within 5km,
    //ordered from nearest to furthest
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.limit = 100
    query.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: point, withinKilometers: 5.0)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            //objects contains the restaurants
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post your code as well? Thanks.

Comment: Hi I just updated the posting with the code I was using. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not loading the table after the geoQuery completes.

Also, you don't need to create a query again inside the geoQuery block. You can call Parse's `loadObjects` method, which would reload data using the `queryForTable()` method.

```
PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {
(point:PFGeoPoint!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        currentLocation = point
        self. loadObjects()
    }
}
```

`currentLocation` should be global within the controller of type `PFGeoPoint`

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I had another quick question.. When I run this in the simulator, it doesn't work. But, when I run it on an actual device, it does work. Do you know what accounts for this discrepancy?